# Placing text inside a box on the slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently one picture on the slide show (using unslider.js) in word press looks like this: 
[image]

my html for each image is like this:

```
 <li style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /images/photos/pearl2.jpg');">

         <h1>The jQuery slider that just slides2 2.</h1>
             <p>No fancy effects or unnecessary markup, and it’s less than 3kb. 2</p>
             <a class="btn" href="#download">Download</a>

         </li>
```

Now what I intent to do is place the h1,p and a anchor on a square box on the right side of the image but I am having hard time figuring out how to go about it. I found that unslider has complete option which can used to do this kind of thing but not sure how to use it. any suggestions regarding the same that I should research on?

current css:

```
body.page-id-7 .banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;

    color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}

body.page-id-7  .banner ul {
        list-style: none;
        width: 300%;
    }


body.page-id-7  .banner ul li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        padding: 160px 0 110px;

        min-height: 400px;

    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
        -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
        -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
        -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-size: 100% 100%;

        box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }
/*body.page-id-7 .banner .placing {position:absolute; background:#ccc; padding:10px; right:0; bottom:0}*/
body.page-id-7  .banner h1, .banner h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
        line-height: 52px;

        color: #fff;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explore your CSS also.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove image from the background of `li` as here `<li style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /images/photos/pearl2.jpg');">`.
And try some different markup and css like placing `div` inside `li` and placing image with `float left` and `h1,p,anchor` to `float right`.

Comment: can't I add multiple background like one at the li level and than 2nd one at the inside div level?

Comment: sky is the limit, whatever you can achieve with html and css inside list items will be used by slider. That is why it is there for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on CSS, Just as a try, Apply following style to `<li>` :-

```
li {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

Fiddle : [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/591/)

```
<div style="position:absolute; background:#ccc; padding:10px; right:0; bottom:0">
         <h1>The jQuery slider that just slides2 2.</h1>
         <p>No fancy effects or unnecessary markup, and it’s less than 3kb. 2</p>
         <a class="btn" href="#download">Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this one and it works only on the last slide and not on every slide that's in the slide show..any idea how to fix it?